# Error in "? :" instruction. Not a statement

Tags: java, if-statement

**This is my code:**

```
public class Zad34 {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

           boolean czyPada = true;
           (czyPada = (czyPada = true) ? System.out.println ("Pada.") : System.out.println ("Niepada."));
    }
}
```

I have an error in `"?:"` instruction line described as `"not a statement"`.

**Question:**

What should I do to improve my code?

Comment: you forgot  the close }

Comment: Also it should be `(czyPada == true)`.

Answer (score 9):

- You are enclosing your statement between parenthesis, which won't compile
- You are using a ternary operator to assign `czyPada` which is a `boolean`, but `System.out.println(..)` returns `void`, not `boolean`

Answer (score 4):

This code has a lot of confusing things going on.

There is no reason to assign a new value to czyPada. It can't change based on anything that the program does.

You should use `?:` for deciding what value to return from an expression, not for side-effects. The parts before and after the colon should be expressions. Statements and method calls with a return type of void are not allowed. (You *could* have each part of the ternary expression call a method that returned something, and also had side-effects like writing to stdout.)

Don't use `=` in a comparison. It does evaluate to the value being set, but that's unnecessary and confusing here. Even `czyPada == true` is unnecessary, czyPada is already a boolean.

To write one string or another based on what czyPada is, it would be better to write:

```
System.out.println(czyPada ? "Pada." : "Nie pada.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't make it complicated it should be like below.

```
 System.out.println(czyPada?"Pada":"Nie Pada.");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well Comparison operator has to be `==` and not `=`.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
System.out.println ((czyPada == true) ? "Pada." : "Nie pada.");
```